# Sharing state from parent to child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I am having an issue binding the state of a parent component to the state of a child.  A look at the code:

Parent Component:

```
    class ParentForm extends React.Component {
        constructor(){
            super();
            this.state = {
                showDialog: false
            };
        }

        toggleDialog() {
            this.setState({showDialog: !this.state.showDialog});
        }

        return (
                <div >
                    <Button color='primary' onClick={() => this.toggleDialog()}></Button>
                    <MyDialog open={this.state.showDialog}/>
                </div>
        );
    }
```

Child Component:

```
export default class MyDialog extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: this.props.open
        };
    }

  handleRequestClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog
          fullScreen
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestClose={() => this.handleRequestClose()}
          transition={<Slide direction="up" />}
        >
         <DialogTitle>{'Title'}</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText>
              This is my dialog
            </DialogContentText>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={() => this.handleRequestClose()} color="primary">Close</Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the Parent Component, if I make the state.showDialog property true, the dialog will open when the page loads. But once I close it one time, I am never able to open it again.  If I have it set to false, it doesn't load when the page loads, and I am never able to open the dialog, even when I click the button on the parent component.  Thank you in advance for taking your time to help.

Comment: You shouldn't be setting a component's state value to a property value. The point is that if you change the property from the parent, this triggers a re-render and this new value is passed to the child and becomes the new value of `this.props.whatever`. So in the child, you should be using `this.props.open`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are setting the local state based on the parent, you need to make use of `componentWillReceiveProps` before **v16.3.0** or `getDerivedStateFromProps/memoization/key modification` thereafter, since your state is set only on the first time and never thereafter. However you don't even need a local state in `MyDialog` component, you can just make use of `Props` and communicate from child to the parent component.

### Parent

```
class ParentForm extends React.Component {
        constructor(){
            super();
            this.state = {
                showDialog: false
            };
        }

        toggleDialog() {
            this.setState({showDialog: !this.state.showDialog});
        }
        closeDialog() {
           this.setState({showDialog: false})
        }
        return (
                <div >
                    <Button color='primary' onClick={ this.toggleDialog}></Button>
                    <MyDialog open={this.state.showDialog} closeDialog={this.closeDialog}/>
                </div>
        );
    }
```

### MyDialog (child)

```
export default class MyDialog extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog fullScreen open={this.props.open} onRequestClose={this.props.closeDialog} transition={<Slide direction="up" />}>
         <DialogTitle>{'Title'}</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText>
              This is my dialog
            </DialogContentText>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={this.props.closeDialog} color="primary">Close</Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, afaiu it's better to do `this.setState((prevState) => ({showDialog: !prevState.showDialog}));` when updating the state.

Comment: This does not share the state at all since the state must be modified only via `setState` as mentioned in the first comment.

Answer (score 2):

handleRequestClose method should be like this.

```
 handleRequestClose = () => {
        this.setState({ open: this.props.open});
      };
```

Edit 1.

You also need to update the parent state when you close the dialog.

```
    toggleDialog(val) {
     if(val){
       this.setState({showDialog: val});
       }else {
     this.setState({showDialog: !this.state.showDialog});
       }
    }

 return (
          <div >
            <Button color='primary' onClick={() => this.toggleDialog()}></Button>
            <MyDialog toggleDialog = {this.toggleDialog} open={this.state.showDialog}/>
          </div>
        );
```

And,

```
 componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps) {//Lifecycle method to get the updated props
    this.setState({ open: nextProps.open });
}

handleRequestClose = () => {
        this.setState({ open: !this.state.open},()=>{
              this.props.toggleDialog (this.state.open);
        });

      };
```

Comment: I have tried that one.  The problem seems to be opening the dialog, since I can't get it to show, I am never able to close the dialog to fire the handleRequestClose method on the child component

Comment: React docs says `componentWillRecieveProps` will be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 2):

Your child component currently only receives the parent's showDialog prop value *once*, only when it's initiated in the constructor.

You need to use `componentWillRecieveProps` and setState of the child's component with the updated value.

So:

`componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ open: nextProps.open });
}`

EDIT: Need to use nextProps, not this.props

```
class ParentForm extends React.Component {
        constructor(){
            super();
            this.state = {
                showDialog: false
            };
        }

        toggleDialog() {
            this.setState({showDialog: !this.state.showDialog});
        }

         closeDialog() {
            this.setState({showDialog: false});
        }

        return (
                <div >
                    <Button color='primary' onClick={() => this.toggleDialog()}></Button>
                    <MyDialog open={this.state.showDialog} closeDialog={() => this.closeDialog()/>
                </div>
        );
}

export default class MyDialog extends Component {
    handleRequestClose = () => {
        this.props.closeDialog();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Dialog
                    fullScreen
                    open={this.state.open}
                    onRequestClose={() => this.handleRequestClose()}
                    transition={<Slide direction="up" />}
                >
                    <DialogTitle>{'Title'}</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>
                        <DialogContentText>
                            This is my dialog
                        </DialogContentText>
                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={() => this.handleRequestClose()} color="primary">Close</Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Should componentWillRecieveProps be a part of child MyDialog class?

Comment: @MiFreidgeimSO-stopbeingevil Yes 